# Scoped css React.js alternative

Tags: css, reactjs, vue.js, iframe, shadow-dom

guys,
We have 2 projects: a parent project in Vue.js, where is only a header and footer and a child project in React.js where is content that we insert into the first Vue.js project.

Each project has its own shared component library and at the same time they are based on another third shared library (which is the same for both component libraries, only the version differs).

The problem is that both component libraries are based on the same (third shared library) and thus have pretty much the same styles - class names. When we insert a React.js project into a Vue.js project, we overwrite the CSS of these shared libraries. The styles from React.js project overwrite styles in header/footer in Vue.js project.

Can you think of any fix? Something like scoped css? Preferably in React.js. We can't edit shared libraries. We tried , insert React.js project into  or Shadow DOM. The last two solutions worked, but it seems drastic to wrap it like that just because css conflicts. Do you think solving it via  or Shadow DOM makes sense in this context?

Comment: Scoped css is possible in react with css modular loader or css in js. It's unclear if it's applicable to your case since you seem to use existing css. Possibly the option is to add a more specific selector to css styles somehow, e.g. in sass it's done like `.custom-theme { @import('theme.css') }`. It's certainly not drastic to use shadow dom in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.